# Custom page slug without creating a WP page

Tags: plugins, urls, rewrite-rules, slug, child-pages

I am developing a WP plugin in which I have a WP page called my-account, but I have some more child pages of its like account-edit, account-misc etc... so I would like to call these pages in this way **mydomain.com/my-account/account-edit** and **mydomain.com/my-account/account-misc** I don't know how to do this without creating WP pages, I have tried some `add_rewrite_rule` but that doesn't work what I expected.

Here is my updated code:

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_account_edit_var', 0, 1);
function add_account_edit_var($vars){
    $vars[] = 'account-edit';
    return $vars;
}

add_action( 'init', 'add_account_edit_rule' );
function add_account_edit_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^my-account/account-edit([^/]*)/?',
        'index.php?pagename=my-account&account-edit',
        'top'
    );
}
```

its working totally fine, I called the url my-account/account-edit/ Page template result: 
**Array ( [pagename] => my-account [account-edit] => )**

Again I added one more rewrite:

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_account_misc_var', 0, 1);
function add_account_misc_var($vars){
    $vars[] = 'account-misc';
    return $vars;
}

add_action( 'init', 'add_account_misc_rule' );
function add_account_misc_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^my-account/account-misc([^/]*)/?',
        'index.php?pagename=my-account&account-misc',
        'top'
    );
}
```

Its not working in template page, I called the url my-account/account-misc/ page loaded but result is 
**Array ( [pagename] => my-account )** not returning "account-misc"

So I cannot check which page etc...

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: @Milo I just updated the question, can you please check now? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, the query var for passing page slug is `pagename`:

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_account_edit_var', 0, 1);
function add_account_edit_var($vars){
    $vars[] = 'account-edit';
    return $vars;
}

add_action( 'init', 'add_account_edit_rule' );
function add_account_edit_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^my-account/([^/]*)/?',
        'index.php?pagename=my-account&account-edit',
        'top'
    );
}
```

To capture the value in your rule, you need to pass the value in `$matches[1]`:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^my-account/([^/]*)/?',
    'index.php?pagename=my-account&account-edit=$matches[1]',
    'top'
);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Since `account-edit` has no value in your rewrite rule, you need to [check if that array key either exists or not](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php).

Comment: Milo, It's working,  but I cannot manage other slugs from page template:
for first query_var I called page url like this: **my-account/account-edit**
and inside this `print_r( $wp->query_vars );` to get current page pagename query, its working fine the result is: 
`Array ( [pagename] => my-account [account-edit] => ) `
But I tried with other query_var I called page url like this: **my-account/account-misc** its not returning query_vars, only just returning: `Array ( [pagename] => my-account )`
I tried with some other slugs too everytime first query working fine not remaining, any guess?

Comment: See edit above.

Comment: no I didn't mean query values, actually, I am not getting query string(pagename) I just updated the questions with my updated code, could you please check?

Comment: I modified a small thing and its working perfectly now!!!!
`'^my-account/([^/]*)/?'` changed to `'^my-account/account-edit([^/]*)/?'`
final code updated in question

Thanks for your time!!!!!